# Can I have C# with functional style and dependency injection?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I want to have some classes which provide a method with

(a) the same name but different implementations;

(b) I also want the methods to be used in the functional/linq-extension style in C#;

(c) I want to compose these classes with others via dependency injection.

It seems this is not possible because static classes, a requirement of (b) in C# cannot implement interfaces, required for (a) or be injected using constructor injection.

I would like to have:

```cs
interface IAlgorithm { double MyFuncStyleMethod(double arg); }

public static class ClassAWithMyExtensionMethods : IAlgorithm
{
  public static double MyFuncStyleMethod(this arg1) { ... }
}

public static class ClassBWithMyExtensionMethods : IAlgorithm
{
  public static double MyFuncStyleMethod(this arg1) { ... }
}

private readonly IAlgorithm _service;
public class MyComposedClass(IAlgorithm service)
{
  _service = service; 
}
...
public double UseMethod(double x)
{
  // want to avoid awkward syntax _service.MyFuncStyleMethod(x);
  double answer = x.MyFuncStyleMethod();
}
```

Is there a way I can have all these benefits?

Comment: Not directly. There is a lot of discussion re: interfaces and extension methods to be found in the C# repo, for example [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1711), and of course the recently implemented [default interface methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods.md). What you propose here couldn't work directly in any case since there's no way for `UseMethod` to actually specify what implementation it wants to use (unless you count selectively importing namespaces as "specifying").

Comment: Never mind, just read the last comment in your sample.

Comment: Have you tried F#? This is the functional go-to of the .NET family. Also, AFAIK, you can intertwine C# with F# in some ways (might not be what you want, and I'm in no way an expert in that matter, just something I heard of).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  DI in the functional world is done with the `Reader` monad.  Here's a bare bones implementation

```
public delegate A Reader<A>(IAlgorithm env);

public static class Reader
{
    public static Reader<A> Pure<A>(A value) =>
        _ => value;

    public static Reader<B> Bind<A, B>(this Reader<A> ma, Func<A, Reader<B>> f) => env =>
        f(ma(env))(env);

    public static Reader<B> Map<A, B>(this Reader<A> ma, Func<A, B> f) =>
        Bind(ma, a => Pure(f(a)));

    public static Reader<B> Select<A, B>(this Reader<A> ma, Func<A, B> f) =>
        Map(ma, f);

    public static Reader<C> SelectMany<A, B, C>(this Reader<A> ma, Func<A, Reader<B>> bind, Func<A, B, C> project) =>
        Bind(ma, a => Map(bind(a), b => project(a, b)));

    public static Reader<IAlgorithm> Ask =>
        env => env;
}
```

It is fixed to the `IAlgorithm` type (it can be generalised by adding an `E` generic parameter to `Reader<A>`

You can then encapsulate the method calls into static `Reader` functions:

```
public static class Example
{ 
    public static Reader<double> MyFuncStyleMethod(double value) =>
        Reader.Ask.Map(env => env.MyFuncStyleMethod(value));
}
```

Example usage is then like so:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static Reader<double> UseMethod(double x, double y) =>
        from a in Example.MyFuncStyleMethod(x)
        from b in Example.MyFuncStyleMethod(y)
        select a + b;
}
```

You can then inject the implementation you want by calling:

```
var env1 = new ClassAWithMyExtensionMethods();
var env2 = new ClassBWithMyExtensionMethods();

var res1 = Test.UseMethod(100, 200)(env1);
var res2 = Test.UseMethod(100, 200)(env2);
```

There's a fully featured `Reader` monad including in [my `language-ext` library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/tree/master/LanguageExt.Core/DataTypes/Reader)